# Root Cron Won't Run Script (permission denied)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cron

I've edited my root cron tab to periodically execute a script located in a particular user's folder using this command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

When cron runs the script, this is the output:

```
sh: 1: /home/user/Location/Of/Script: Permission denied
```

I thought that the root cron had permission to do anything. I have no issue when I manually run this script as root.

I've read in the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) that further error info can be found here:

```
sudo cat /var/log/syslog
```

Here's what I found:

```
Jan 30 12:30:01 backup CRON[17702]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

However, I think this is probably unrelated to the permission denied issue.

So what do I really need to do?

Comment: Can you list permissions on `/home/user/Location/Of/Script`? E.g. `la -l /home/user/Location/Of/Script`. Incidentally, you need an MTA installed for normal internal use, even if you are not sending/receiving email externally. I'm surprised your system does not have it already installed.

Comment: This could be due to all sorts of things. Please post the output of the command @FaheemMitha requested as well as the relevant line in your crontab

Comment: -rw-r--r-- (this was the issue) -Thank you

Comment: You say you solved it with "-rw-r--r--" but I don't know what that is or how to use it and I have the same issue as described in this thread. Can you be a bit more specific with your solution for posterity? People like me will be really grateful for it. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnsonJason : The issue was that the permissions on the script-file did not permit execution. Look at the accepted answer, which shows how to give the script permission to execute.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think that your script is not executable. So, use the following command to make it:

```
chmod +x /home/user/Location/Of/Script
```

Or, if you are not the owner of that script:

```
sudo chmod +x /home/user/Location/Of/Script
```

Comment: So for cron to run the script it must be executable, but manually as root doesn't need this flag, right?

Comment: Depends how you run the script manually. If you run the script using `./Scipt` or `/home/user/Location/Of/Script` it's not ok. Generally any script must to be executable. See [How to run a shell script in Linux](http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/08/run-shell-script-linux.html).

Comment: That makes sense, but I really have been running this script manually the ./script way without encountering any permissions issues until I tried to cron it. Thanks for you help.